# Kendo Filter widget can support relative fields for filtering?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to implement filter which can support relative fields i.e. the first field would be table names once user choose any table then second field gets populated with all columns available for selected table. Now users can choose operator and pass value for filtering the column value. So basically I want to filter on basis of column's value. As I dont want to put all columns for all tables in one field because that makes my drop down very long as I have huge columns in some table and also user wont be able to search specific column easily hence I want to introduce one more field which is table drop down. Once user select from table drop down then column dropdown will only have selected table column which reduce the columns number and user can choose easily. see the attached screenshot for same.  So the expression preview should be something like .   e.g. "table1.column5 is equal to myvalue". How we can achieve this ? I tried using editortemplate of field property of kendo Filter widget and added field 2 as shown in attached screen shot but after that not able to get field 2 value in expression. Can someone suggest what are the other ways we can achieve this ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recieved the answer for this question by telerik support team. Posting same here to help someone in future:

I went through several different scenarios, however the desired functionality is not supported with the current implementation of the Filter widget. The reason is that the filter that you see in the expression preview - "field is equal to value", is based upon the filter fields in the widget's and datasource configurations.
Example:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: data,
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          name: { type: "string" },
          age: { type: "number" },
          city: {type: "string"},
          money: {type: "number"}
        }
      }
    }
```

In this case the name of the field must be one that is available in the model.fields configuration. In other words, in order for the filter to work properly, you'll need to have all of the table.column combinations inside the schema, example:

```
fields: {
          table1.name: { type: "string" },
          table1.age: { type: "number" },
          table1.city: {type: "string"},
          table1.money: {type: "number"},
          table2.age: { type: "number" },
          table2.city: {type: "string"},
          table2.money: {type: "number"},
          table3.age: { type: "number" },
          table3.city: {type: "string"},
          table4.money: {type: "number"},
          ...
        }
```

An alternative approach that I can suggest is to filter the second dropdownlist based on the selection of the first. You should keep in mind that this doesn't change the expression itself, in other words you still won't be able to create a filter that has a table.column field name.
Example, table1 is selected in the first dropdown and we have name and age options in the second one:

Example, table2 is selected in the first dropdown and we have city and money options in the second one:

I've prepared an example which demonstrates the above functionality:
https://dojo.telerik.com/@gdenchev/AHAmocIM

DOJO link content in case link disabled in future:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.119/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <div id="filter"></div>
        <br /><br />
        <script>
          var data = [
            { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, city: "City1", money: 60 },
            { name: "John Doe", age: 33, city: "City2", money: 90 }
          ];
    
          var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: data,
            schema: {
              model: {
                fields: {
                  name: { type: "string" },
                  age: { type: "number" },
                  city: {type: "string"},
                  money: {type: "number"}
                }
              }
            }
          });
    
          $("#filter").kendoFilter({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            expressionPreview: true
          });
    
          $(".k-filter-toolbar-item:eq(1)").on("click", function(e) {
            let filter = $("#filter").data("kendoFilter");
            filter.one("change", function(e) {
              let filterRow = $(".k-filter-item:last").find(".k-filter-field");
              let firstDropDown = filterRow.find("select").data("kendoDropDownList");
              let secondDropDown = $("<input />")
              .insertBefore(filterRow)
              .kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: {
                  data: ["table1", "table2"]
                },
                change: function() {
                  let value = this.value();
                  let columnsForTableOne = [{text: "name", value: "name"},{text: "age", value: "age"}];
                  let columnsForTableTwo = [{text: "city", value: "city"},{text: "money", value: "money"}];
                  let data;
                  
                  switch(value) {
                    case "table1": data = columnsForTableOne;
                      break;
                    case "table2": data = columnsForTableTwo;
                      break;
                  }
                  firstDropDown.dataSource.data(data);
                }
              }).data("kendoDropDownList");
            });
          });
    
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.119/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <div id="filter"></div>
        <br /><br />
        <script>
          var data = [
            { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, city: "City1", money: 60 },
            { name: "John Doe", age: 33, city: "City2", money: 90 }
          ];
    
          var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: data,
            schema: {
              model: {
                fields: {
                  name: { type: "string" },
                  age: { type: "number" },
                  city: {type: "string"},
                  money: {type: "number"}
                }
              }
            }
          });
    
          $("#filter").kendoFilter({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            expressionPreview: true
          });
    
          $(".k-filter-toolbar-item:eq(1)").on("click", function(e) {
            let filter = $("#filter").data("kendoFilter");
            filter.one("change", function(e) {
              let filterRow = $(".k-filter-item:last").find(".k-filter-field");
              let firstDropDown = filterRow.find("select").data("kendoDropDownList");
              let secondDropDown = $("<input />")
              .insertBefore(filterRow)
              .kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: {
                  data: ["table1", "table2"]
                },
                change: function() {
                  let value = this.value();
                  let columnsForTableOne = [{text: "name", value: "name"},{text: "age", value: "age"}];
                  let columnsForTableTwo = [{text: "city", value: "city"},{text: "money", value: "money"}];
                  let data;
                  
                  switch(value) {
                    case "table1": data = columnsForTableOne;
                      break;
                    case "table2": data = columnsForTableTwo;
                      break;
                  }
                  firstDropDown.dataSource.data(data);
                }
              }).data("kendoDropDownList");
            });
          });
    
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**